# Wordpress plugin- rank users by number of posts

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I want to create a simple plugin for wordpress -rank users based of number of user posts. Already i have this code and i don't know how to sort array 
and display it in table

```
global $wpdb; 
$result = count_users();
$users = $result['total_users'];

for($id = 1;$id<$users;$id++){ 
    $result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.display_name, COUNT(wp_posts.post_author) AS 'Number_of_posts' 
        FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_posts ON wp_users.ID = wp_posts.post_author 
        WHERE wp_posts.post_type = 'post'             
        AND wp_users.ID = $id", ARRAY_A);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Array sorting in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

You could iterate through the WPDB object and do whatever logic you need and put values into an associative array. Sort it using the appropriate function from the PHP docs linked

Displaying data from an array in an html table would look something like this:

```
<table>
   <tr>
       <th>Rank</th>
       <th>Username</th>
       <th>Post Count</th>
   </tr>
<?php
$i = 1;
foreach($array as $value){?>
       <tr>
          <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['user']; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $value['posts']; ?></td>
       </tr>
<?php 
      $i++;
} ?>
</table>
```